# How can I assign a smarty variable to a PHP variable

Tags: php, smarty

How can I assign a smarty variable to a PHP variable. I have

```
{assign var=arrayname value="/"|explode:$form.attributes}
{assign var=id value=$arrayname.2}
```

I want to assign the smarty variable id to a php variable

```
<?php  
    // I want $id here 
?>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand...how was your $arrayname passed to Smarty....? I assume you have used something like

```
<?php
$smarty->assign('arrayname',$arrayvariable)
?>
```

So in PHP there is equation:

```
$you_have_wanted==$arrayvariable[2]
```

Comment: i made some change .Please have a look

Comment: Smarty is a translator which gets values from PHP or config files and then generates HTML, XML or else. Smarty is anyway a tool of PHP  that runs at server side. Your $userid can NOT come from user form and may not come from Smarty's calculation in parsing(i have not learned this up to now) except from its reading config file.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a situation you should find yourself in.

You should be able to either do what you want to do entirely in smarty or entirely in php.

If you explain in detail what your trying to do we can help you with one or the other

Comment: i think we can use php commands also in smarty template page. i have to set one session value from my smarty template depending on the user id. so array key should be user id. i think we couln't asssign session using smarty. So i tried to assign session using php. so i have to get the userid which is a smarty variable to php variable i tried get_template_vars(), but not works

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [use php in a smarty template](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php) but:

> "This is for advanced users only, **not normally needed and not recommended**."

The whole point of the smarty template is to keep your business logic in a separate view.
Therefore you should deal with your variables in the php page then assign them to the template as in Lucifer Orichalcum's example.

If the user Id value you a trying to retrieve comes from a form you have to deal with the form values in the .php file ($_POST['id']) not in the .tpl 
Same rule for your sessions variables.

Can you tell us more about where the Id comes from in the first place ?